# finding old AD machines

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I found this code on Microsofts script center site.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$domain = "ourdomain.org"
$DaysInactive = 90
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
$sourceOU = 'OU=All_Workstations,DC=ourdomain,DC=org'
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp -SearchBase $sourceOU |
  Select-Object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} |
  Export-Csv "c:\temp\OLD_Computers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I ran this code and it created the CSV file.  I then ran a ping script against the computer names it found.   Half of the machines were online and pingable.
so what constitutes "inactive"?  If half of my machines are still online and I can ping them then this script does not seem to be of much use.

Comment: What constitutes inactive - if the lastLogonTimestamp hasn't been updated in 90 days. What updates it? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/ says it's interactive logons, network and service logons. Is nobody using the computers? Is your AD replication broken? Is your domain not at 2003 domain functional level or higher? Are you certain the IP addresses for those names point to those actual computers and not other computers or other things?

Comment: +1 What @TessellatingHeckler said about 2003+ and AD-repl. problems. Also: 1. This is an AD/computer management-question and belongs on Server Fault. 2. Are you sure they were the same computers and not just old DNS-records that should have been scavenged a long time ago? . Try checking against `pwdlastset` too. It is updated every 30 days (or the interval of your password policy) unless someone disabled it on the client

Answer (score 0):

Try using lastLogonDate instead of LastLogonTimeStamp

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$domain = "ourdomain.org"
$DaysInactive = 90
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
$sourceOU = 'OU=All_Workstations,DC=ourdomain,DC=org'
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonDate -lt $time} -Properties LastLogonDate -SearchBase $sourceOU |
Select-Object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonDate)}} |
Export-Csv "c:\temp\OLD_Computers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you.  sorry it has been a while since I've gotten back to this post.  But....  even this code (using LastLogonDate) does not work.  I get a list of a few hundred machines and then I ping that list and half of the machines are online.

Comment: I hit enter before I finished.    I know we have replaced many laptops/desktops with newer hardware and the new hardware gets a new name (based on asset tag info) so the old computer is removed from the environment.      . Is there no way to accurately find machines that are "dead records" from AD?

Comment: This is the code i used to find old computer on my domain

Comment: sorry i hit enter too  $then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) # 30 jours depuis le dernier logon

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate,Description,MemberOf -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then}

Comment: i hate that i can hit enter to change row                                                                                                                                    $then = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) 

Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate,Description,MemberOf -Filter {lastLogonDate -lt $then}

Answer (score 0):

You need to also address the "PasswordLastSet" attribute

You can use this link to help you understand more on what to look for:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ken_brumfield/2008/09/16/identifying-stale-user-and-computer-accounts/